# How do I get the confidence score from cv::ml::RTrees?

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, random-forest

I have a `cv::ml::RTrees classifier`. How do I get the confidence score from the classifier, i.e., the probability of the sample belonging to the returned class when running prediction? I have tried `predict` and `getVotes` methods, but both of them return the class label, without the probability.

Comment: did you try to specify [RAW_OUTPUT](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d7d/classcv_1_1ml_1_1StatModel.html#af1ea864e1c19796e6264ebb3950c0b9a) ?

Comment: @berak yup, tried the following code, it returns the label

Comment: i was more guessing, [looking e.g. here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/ml/src/rtrees.cpp#L385-L396)

Comment: ah wait, i think, [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/ml/src/rtrees.cpp#L381) means, it only works with a *2 class regression* not with multi class classification